# Is sorting a table by a time field (where auto_now_add=True), equivalent to sorting it by the said table's primary key ID?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

Imagine a database table with a `time_of_insert` attribute, which is auto-filled by the current time for every INSERT (e.g. in a Django model's example, the attribute has `auto_now_add=True`).

In that case, is sorting the said table by `time_of_insert` equivalent to sorting it by each row's ID (primary key)?

**Background:** I ask because I have a table where I have an auto created `time_of_insert` attribute. I'm currently sorting the said table by `time_of_insert`; this field isn't indexed. I feel I can simply sort it by `id`, instead of indexing `time_of_insert` - that way I get fast results AND I don't have to incur the over-head of indexing one more table column. My DB is postgres.

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be close enough for most applications.  There may be some race conditions, particularly on parallel databases.  This depends deeply on how the insert time and id are created, which is highly database dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's not.

`id` guarantees uniqueness. And your datetime column does not.

So in case if there are 2 rows with the same `time_of_insert` value - then the result set order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @HassanBaig I would suggest you to sort by both `ORDER BY time_of_insert, id`